# Fusion Charts: How to hide values of Pie Chart

Tags: php, fusioncharts

Referring the [URL](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/free/Contents/ChartSS/Images/XML_3DPie1.gif), how can I hide values around Pie chart? I need to do it to consume the space. I am unable to find the way to do it.

I am using Free version of Fusion Charts

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<chart [..........] showLabels='0' showValues='0' [...........]  >
```

Comment: @All: showNames='0' needs to be used to hide the labels, whereas showValues='0' will hide the values associated with the labels.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `showNames='0' showValues='0'` in the `<chart>` element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these configuration to hide values for pie

```
 "showlabels": "0",
 "showvalues": "0"
```

Reference code -

```
    FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
    type: 'pie2d',
    renderAt: 'chart-container',
    width: '550',
    height: '350',
    dataFormat: 'json',
    dataSource: {
      "chart": {
        "caption": "Split of revenue by product categories",
        "subCaption": "Last year",
        "numberPrefix": "$",
        "showPercentInTooltip": "0",
        "decimals": "1",
        //Theme
        "theme": "fusion",
        "tooltipBorderRadius": "20",
        
        // hide lables & values
        "showlabels": "0",
            "showvalues": "0"
      },
      "data": [{
          "label": "Food",
          "value": "285040"
        },
        {
          "label": "Apparels",
          "value": "146330"
        },
        {
          "label": "Electronics",
          "value": "105070"
        },
        {
          "label": "Household",
          "value": "49100"
        }
      ]
    }
  }).render();

});
```

Reference [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t02j9rg8/)